# Отображение HTML полученного в JSON

Tags: jquery, json, html

На запрос клиента сервр отвечает валидным JSON, один параметр - это строка (которая есть ссылка в виде html'e).

При отображение его на странице вижу как текст, НЕ как ссылку.

На клиенте использую JQuery, backbone

[Ответ от сервера](http://pastebin.com/H7JSBYdK)

[HTML клиента](http://pastebin.com/L42mgdWM)

[Скриншот](http://i46.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0505/6e/21f49caf11a7882605e274555527946e.png)

Comment: Всё, что вы показали - это прекрасно, но как вы выводите полученные данные? Если **$('some_block').text(str);**, то ничего удивительного, т.к. для вставки html-кода, существует методы **.html()**, **.append()** и иже с ними.

Comment: <blockquote>$(this.el).setTemplateURL("../blocks/main/b-contests.tpl");    
      
      var contests;
      
      App.doPostAction('request/GetContests', {}, function(resultData){
       contests = resultData['contests'];
   });
            
            $(this.el).processTemplate(contests);</blockquote>

Comment: К сожалению, мне это ни о чем не говорит, но что-то подсказывает, что метод **processTemplate()** обрабатывает данные, преобразовывая html-теги в мнемоники.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена, вы были правы, нашел исходники (jQuery template), processTemplate, по умолчанию обрабатывает данные, для отключения обработки необходимио передавать парамметры (`filter_data`):

```
        $(this.el).setTemplateURL("template.tpl", data, {filter_data: false});
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перед вставкой ответа, обработать его вот такой функцией

```
function htmlspecialchars_decode(string) {
    var e = document.createElement('div'); 
    e.innerHTML = string; 
    try {
        var res = e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    } catch(e) {
        return string;
    }
    if (res === null) {
        return string;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: Не помоголо, получил "ничего", а собственно идея в чем, вставить полученые данные на прямую?

Comment: Идея в том, что у вас в ответе сервера возможно html теги заменены мнемониками http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_HTML или как предположил @Deonis позже заменяются. Эта функция, как видно из ее названия, приводит html к нормальному виду.

Answer (score 0):

Если используются `underscore template`, то можно просто сделать `<%= _.unescape(Date) %>`